# How to determine the k in kNN

Tags: machine-learning, k-nn

I'm looking to use the k-Nearest Neighbors (kNN) algorithm.  What are the possible methods for determining the best K?  From what I have read, looking at many different values(say 10-100) should work, but that's a big range.

How can I reduce the range of possible K's I should test?

Comment: Don't you mean k?

Comment: You could use GridSerchCV, RandomSearchCV, or BayesianOptimization to find the best hyperparameters if you are using Python

Comment: The K in kNN is a hyperparameter. You should look for: how to optimize a hyperparameter.

Comment: how do you tune any ML algorithm? Do a grid search on a small subset of the data in question.

Comment: ebrahimi and Mohammad Athar those both sound like answers not comments. If you post it as an answer then others can vote it up in agreement